# Computing relative dates in php using strtotime()

Tags: php, strtotime

I'm looking for a reliable way to return the full date of a specified weekday (e.g. "Mon") for the *current* week.

Since today is Wednesday, June 13, 2012, I expected `<?php echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime('Mon this week')); ?>` to result in `2012-06-11`, but instead php returns `2012-06-18` as though it interprets **this week** as meaning **next week**.  Why this behavior and what should I be doing?

Thanks.

--Jeff

Comment: How do you define "this week"? Monday though Sunday? Sunday through Saturday? Saturday through Friday? Or something else completely?

Comment: interesting.  I just ran it under PHP5.4, and got the 11th for 'Mon this week' and the 18th for 'this Mon'.  What version PHP are you running?

Comment: also, I assumed that a "week" started either on Sunday or Monday since the date() formats give options for both

Comment: How about `<?php echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime('last Mon',time())); ?>`?

Comment: does it give the same wrong date when you use a DateTime object? e.g. `$d=new DateTime('Mon this week'); echo $d->format('Y-m-d');`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( 'last Monday', strtotime( 'Sunday' ) ) );`

This searches for the Monday previous to the next Sunday.

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation [php relative date formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php).

Then `Monday this week` would first advance to the `next Monday` and then process the relative text of `this week`.

**dayname**: Moves to the next day of this name unless it is the current day then it will not advance.  In other words if the current date was June 11, then `strtotime('Monday this week')` would return June 11 whereas if the current date was June 13 then `strtotime('Monday this week')` would return June 19.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is the solution for your problem:

```
$monday_date = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0,0,0, date("m"), date("j")-(date("w")+1), date("Y")));
```