# Discussion of `strtotime` problems eg "this x day " when day not = x gives NEXT x. ESOTERIC pls ignore

Tags: php, strtotime, date-manipulation

EDIT: Two minuses in under a minute. I thought this was a tiny but interesting query.

ORIGINAL QUERY: I am generating a five week calender into which I will pour info (the day and date and other stuff).

I want the top left cell to be the "current" Sunday.

For example if today is Weds 12th then I need to find Sun 9th as the start for the run. Then I just do a `$var = strtotime("+1 day", $var)` for the next 34 slots.

My problem is doing this neatly if today is Sunday.

At present I have:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Pacific/Honolulu");
$day_now = time();
$current_day= date ("D", $day_now);
if ($current_day == "Sun") 
{$day_now = strtotime("+1 day", $day_now);} 
$day_now = strtotime("last sunday"); 
//do stuff/
```

I just wondered if there was a more "tidy" way of doing this.

I tried "this sunday, last sunday, sunday this week" but could find nothing that would pick today as the Sunday and ALSO work for the rest of the week.

Just curious if anyone has found a form of words that works for this with `strtotime`.

Comment: This is very simple: while today not > Sunday, subtract one day and check again. Make that a function that returns the date of the first Sunday it hits.

Comment: Thanks for that - that is sort of what I am doing. I was just curious about a more elegant way of doing IDEALLY with a single `strtotime` expression. `strtotime` is pretty good but I built a huge time interpreter to improve time setting by 10% so just curious about the finer working of `strtotime`. I had hope that "this sunday' would work but it doesn't

Comment: `date('w')` tells you what the day-of-week is. Sunday = 0. So if date says 'w' is 5, you'll know you're on Friday, and sunday was 5 days ago.

Comment: Marc thanks but I can do that fine with the code I have. I am just interested in the functionality of `strtotime` in this post. In other word NO CONDITIONALS would be needed if "This Sunday" worked as I had hoped.

Comment: `strtotime('this Sunday')` will give you today if today is Sunday, but if not then it gives you *next* Sunday. That's pretty stupid but that's how it works.

Comment: Thanks: Is there an expression that, on a Sunday, will give you that date and on the Mon, Tues, Weds will give you the same? I thought "this Sunday" might but it did not (or so I recall from testing yesterday). This is just an academic question for my own interest. I like neat code that is all and I feel that this (or something like it)  SHOULD work. I just tried "Sunday this week" but nope.

Comment: `strtotime('this Monday')` will also give you today if today is Monday but next Monday if not.  So `this` basically means `next` unless you happen to be on that exact day.

Comment: @developerwjk thanks that is EXACTLY what I was talking about. `strtotime` seems to have got a lot better on time (though could still be better) but this, to me was crazy. I begin to think there is no correct "phrase". Thank you for reminding me it was the weird behaviour of "this sunday" that sent me down this rabbit hole.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange behaviour of strtotime() when using relative dates ('this week')](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21517414/strange-behaviour-of-strtotime-when-using-relative-dates-this-week)

Comment: Actually, I think I found the exact answer you're looking for here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022384/computing-relative-dates-in-php-using-strtotime?rq=1 `date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( 'last Monday', strtotime( 'Sunday' ) ) );`

Comment: @developerwjk I think the answer I need is "No there is no way of doing this in simple `strtotime`" and yep the other link looks pretty close to this. I searched but found lots of `strtotime` threads but not that one. To be honest happy with my solution - not 100% elegant but very transparent.

Comment: `strtotime( 'last Sunday', strtotime( 'Sunday' ) )`: Sunday between last Sunday and next Sunday, which is always what we really mean by 'this Sunday'.

Answer (score 0):

OK `strtotime` has NO one phrase solution to the current query ('this sunday" for the whole week). (I would call it a bug!)

The linked discussions

[Strange behaviour of strtotime() when using relative dates ('this week')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21517414/strange-behaviour-of-strtotime-when-using-relative-dates-this-week)

and

[Computing relative dates in php using strtotime()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022384/computing-relative-dates-in-php-using-strtotime?rq=1)

offer solutions.

I like my current solution - while not elegant it is very readable and I know that if I come back to it in a couple of years I will understand what is going on.

Hopefully "this sunday" will be fixed someday in`strtotime`.

Thanks for the input.